# mod_rewrite not behaving nicely

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a simple project in which I'm attempting to do some rewriting of URLs to point to a couple PHP scripts.

My current path on the server is /project/engine, and I've dropped an .htaccess file in that directory to perform my rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(get|post)/(\w+)$ $1.$2.php
```

It's a pretty simple rewrite. I'm basically looking to rewrite a URL like this: `/project/engine/get/class` to this: `/project/engine/get.class.php`.

Can anyone spot the error here? If I try accessing the URL in a web browser, I get a 404 and the following error in Apache error log:

```
[Wed Dec 29 14:57:17 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/project/engine/get (None could be negotiated).
```

My apache configuration file looks like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

### EDIT

Here's a dump from my Apache access and error logs.

`tail /var/log/apache2/access.log`:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Dec/2010:18:04:22 -0800] "GET /project/engine/get/questionnaire HTTP/1.1" 404 518 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.200 Safari/534.10"
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Dec/2010:18:04:23 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 500 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.200 Safari/534.10"
```

`tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Wed Dec 29 18:04:22 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/project/engine/get (None could be negotiated).
[Wed Dec 29 18:04:23 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

Also, here is my apache2.conf file:

```
#
# Based upon the NCSA server configuration files originally by Rob McCool.
#
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ for detailed information about
# the directives.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# The configuration directives are grouped into three basic sections:
#  1. Directives that control the operation of the Apache server process as a
#     whole (the 'global environment').
#  2. Directives that define the parameters of the 'main' or 'default' server,
#     which responds to requests that aren't handled by a virtual host.
#     These directives also provide default values for the settings
#     of all virtual hosts.
#  3. Settings for virtual hosts, which allow Web requests to be sent to
#     different IP addresses or hostnames and have them handled by the
#     same Apache server process.
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "/var/log/apache2/foo.log"
# with ServerRoot set to "" will be interpreted by the
# server as "//var/log/apache2/foo.log".
#

### Section 1: Global Environment
#
# The directives in this section affect the overall operation of Apache,
# such as the number of concurrent requests it can handle or where it
# can find its configuration files.
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the LockFile documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs-2.1/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#<IfModule !mpm_winnt.c>
#<IfModule !mpm_netware.c>
LockFile /var/lock/apache2/accept.lock
#</IfModule>
#</IfModule>

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 15

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
## 

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# event MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          150
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#

AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

#
# DefaultType is the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain


#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include all the user configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

# Include ports listing
Include /etc/apache2/ports.conf

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
# If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

#
# Define an access log for VirtualHosts that don't define their own logfile
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log vhost_combined


# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include /etc/apache2/conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

as well as the actual file which "loads" the mod_rewrite module:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

### EDIT AGAIN

Here's my rewrite log, finally got it working, but rewriting isn't working yet.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2011:16:08:38 --0800] [localhost/sid#7f1b3e7ae218][rid#7f1b3ebe82e8/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /project/engine/get/questionnaire
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2011:16:08:38 --0800] [localhost/sid#7f1b3e7ae218][rid#7f1b3ebe82e8/initial] (1) pass through /project/engine/get/questionnaire
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2011:16:08:38 --0800] [localhost/sid#7f1b3e7ae218][rid#7f1b3ebec308/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /favicon.ico
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2011:16:08:38 --0800] [localhost/sid#7f1b3e7ae218][rid#7f1b3ebec308/initial] (1) pass through /favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your error message talk about negociation (remove mod_negociate if you do not need multi-language handling).

For now remove the Multiviews options on your directory.

And then increase mod_rewrite loglevel to 9 and set a rewritelog file to get a trace.

**EDIT:** To remove the module that you do not need you can use the command a2dismod (which means **a**-pache-**2 dis**-able **mod**-ules). And you can re-enable them with a2enmod. Remove negociation module.

If something is wrong in your configuration after the module disabling you'll get a notice of the line to modify in the logs.

You can as well disable MultiViews in per-Directory settings, as it is done in your cgi-bin directory with the Options line. Add a Directory configuration for your project;

```
<Directory /var/www/project>
    AllowOverride None
    Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: How would I do this? I have added my log file output in the post above.

Comment: check the edit. Your rewrite log file does only concern the favicon and not the project, do you only have favicon requests in it?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(get|post)/(\w+)$ $1$2.$3.php
```

or this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(get|post)/(\w+)$ $1/$2.$3.php
```

Comment: ok, we need more info then... add logging... http://www.latenightpc.com/blog/archives/2007/09/05/a-couple-ways-to-debug-mod_rewrite

Comment: Did that, log file was created but I get no output from it whatsoever.

Comment: well, im out of ideas for today and its going home time... good luck.  If I think of anything tonight I will post it.

Comment: ok, one last try... look at this post... http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3161107.htm

Comment: you should post from the access log and show the URLs it thinks you are sending in.  Somehow its not matching your URL to the rule I think.

Comment: Added access and error log above to help in debugging. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the logs... all I can guess on is that you dont have mod_rewrite configured correctly in httpd.conf.  Can you please post the part of the config that has the module loading.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this by avoiding a directory starting with a capital letter. In case anyone got the same problem.