# Why are some of my mod_rewrite rules not working?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^es$ index.php?lang=es_ES [L]
RewriteRule ^pt$ index.php?lang=pt_BR [L]
RewriteRule ^en$ index.php?lang=en_US [L]

RewriteRule ^index.php index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^inicio$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^nosotros$ us.php [L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio$ portfolio-masonry.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contacto$ contact.php [L]

RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^us$ us.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [L]

RewriteRule ^proyectos/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ portfolio-single.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^projects/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ portfolio-single.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

And here is the site: http://testing.fyrastudio.com/WEB_fyrastudio.com/v3/

Everything is working great. But if you choose to see the site in english, and then click on About us, or Contact, the server returns a 404 not found error. 
But according to these two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^us$ us.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [L]
```

it should be working just like the rest of the site!

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the following fixed my issue, but it did. Following this question:

[mod_rewrite not behaving nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558629/mod-rewrite-not-behaving-nicely)

I disabled mod_negotiation and everything started working...

If anyone can explain why and/or what this module does, I would appreciate it.