# URL rewriting using .htaccess - 404 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've set up a LAMP stack on my Raspberry Pi as a development environment for my website.

I am trying to implement URL rewriting to make my URLs prettier, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I have tried the following:
`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`
and under the `var/www` section changed the line `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

I was getting a Internal Server 500 error, so I ran a command to allow the server to use the `.htaccess` file (can't remember the command now).

I also restarted the server and Raspberry Pi.

I no longer get the error, but when I look in the error log by using the command
`tail -f  /var/log/apache2/error.log` I get a 404 Not Found error.

Here's my .htaccess file (it's really simple for now).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^photography$ photography.php
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, and whether it is a server configuration issue or a programming error. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: [mod_rewrite not behaving nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558629/mod-rewrite-not-behaving-nicely)

Edited the line in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` file to be:

`Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks`

Answer (score 1):

Just, try this code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^photography$ /photography.php
```

Comment: Looking at the server logs, I still get the following: `Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/photography (None could be negotiated).`

Comment: And if you try to access to your site with photography, do you have a 404 error ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was a config issue. Will post an answer now.